# graph the contents of a matrix in python (using matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I need to graph the contents of a matrix where each row represents a different feature and each column is a different time point. In other words, I want to see the change in features over time and I have stacked each feature in the form of a matrix. C is the matrix

```
A=C.tolist() #convert matrix to list.
R=[]
for i in xrange(len(A[0])):
    R+=[[i]*len(A[i])]    
for j in xrange(len(A[0])):
    S=[]
    S=C[0:len(C)][j]
    pylab.plot(R[j],S,'r*')
pylab.show()
```

Is this right/is there a more efficient way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract column i of a matrix M with `M[:,i]` and the number of columns in M is given by `M.shape[1]`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = range(M.shape[0])

for i in range(M.shape[1]):
    plt.plot(T, M[:,i])

plt.show()
```

This assumes that the rows represent equally spaced timeslices.

Comment: Actually, you can do it a lot easier with `plt.plot(M.T)` - as in the answer below.

Answer (score 9):

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot):

> ```
> matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args, **kwargs):
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> plot(y)            # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1
> plot(y, 'r+')      # ditto, but with red plusses
> ```
>
> If x and/or y is 2-dimensional, then the corresponding columns will be
>   plotted.

So if `A` has the values in columns, it is as simple as:

```
pylab.plot(A, 'r*')  # making all red might be confusing, '*-' might be better
```

If your data is in rows, then plot the transpose of it:

```
pylab.plot(A.T, 'r*')
```